# jquery function works correctly only on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
$(".plusmenus1").on('click', function() {
    $('.plusmenus1 i').toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
    $("#care_and_washing").toggleClass("collapsed_MB  ");
    changeHeight();
});
$(".plusmenus2").on('click', function() {
    $('.plusmenus2 i').toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    changeHeight();
});

function changeHeight() {
    var divHeight = $("#care_and_washing").height() + $("#demo").height();

    if (!$("#care_and_washing").hasClass("collapsed_MB")) {
        $('#careheight').css('height', divHeight + 'px');
    } else {
        $('#careheight').css('height', '10px');
    }
}
```

it works but it gets the `var divHeight = $("#care_and_washing").height() + $("#demo").height();`correctly only on the first click after that it gets the `var` without the + so it adds the `height` only of the `#care_and_washing`

HTML (I'll try to add only what's needed)

```
<div class="plusmenus1"><i data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="float: left; position: relative; top: 3px; padding-right: 5px; color: black; font-size: 10px;" class="fa fa-plus collapsed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="care_and_washing" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="collapsed collapsed_MB" style="font-family: 'NiveauGroteskMedium'; font-size: 11px; color: black;">Care & Washing</p>
</div>
<div style="cursor: default; padding-left: 13px;" id="demo" class="collapse">
<p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Dry Flat</p>
<p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Do Not Bleach</p>
<p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Tumble Dry Low</p>
<p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Iron Low</p>
<p style="font-family: Questrial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">• Hand Wash</p>
</div>

<div id="careheight" ></div>
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you show your html too.

Comment: @Dodorido ok let me add it

Comment: @ Marwane, seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/mt7rtvvb/

Comment: @Dodorido on my localhost page it starts with 10px then 155px then back to 10 px and it's correct but if I click again it gives 18px instead of 155 then back again to 10px

Comment: I see, I suggest to create a jsFiddle or something, recreating this specific behaviour, otherwise it's quite difficult to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I have a note: you can't get `.height();` of hidden element. if you use `display:none` or `.hide();` with your `#demo`

Comment: Maybe you have other elements with the same id. Or maybe its the collapse class on the #demo element.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer i believe that's the problem, but why it gets the height of that element the first time i click?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap JS collapse? If so the height is read before the CSS transitions are complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hidden_Element.height()` and `Hidden_Element.width()` will be `0` so you need to show to get height and hide again like this

```
function changeHeight() {
  var care_h = $("#care_and_washing").height();
  var demo_h = $("#demo").height();

  demo_h = demo_h == 0 ? $("#demo").show().height() : demo_h;

  $("#demo").hide();

  var divHeight = care_h + demo_h;

  if (!$("#care_and_washing").hasClass("collapsed_MB")) {
    $('#careheight').css('height', divHeight + 'px');
  } else {
    $('#careheight').css('height', '10px');
  }
}
```